# Cron job issue with FTP

Tags: laravel, iis, cron

I am currently monitoring a cron job responsible for uploading PDF files to an FTP server. This particular cron job has been running smoothly for the past two years. However, within the last month, it has started encountering an error. The error is not consistent but occurs twice a week.

Interestingly, when I manually execute the same method from a browser, it works without any issues. I'm seeking assistance in understanding the reason behind this successful execution through the browser.

For context, the script is written in Laravel 5.5.* and is hosted on an IIS Windows server.

Error:

ftp_put(): Error while transferring data: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted.

Comment: If your script runs fine in a web browser, but fails to run with a cron job, it means your cron job is not set up correctly. Another reason could be user account permissions, make sure the user account running the cron job has the necessary permissions to access the FTP server and write files. Also, check for any environmental differences between the cron job execution and the manual browser execution, such as different environment variables or configuration settings.

Comment: If the problem is intermittent, it may be related to server load during certain periods of time. If the server load is high, network connections, including FTP transfers, may be affected. Please check for network congestion, peak usage times, or other network-related factors.